# LeafletCRS projection issues

Tags: r, coordinate-system, leaflet, leaflet-r, shiny

I am trying to get a map in the Dutch Rijksdriehoekstelsel coordinates in a Leaflet map in R that is going in a Shiny app later. I am going to have to add polygons later, and changing their X and Y coordinates into the WGS84 would be horrible. I stole the proj4def and resolutions from the example posted at the bottom. However, I just get a grey screen with the zoom in and out buttons. Either I have screwed up the leafletOptions or the tileLayer.

```
library(leaflet)

leaflet(
 options =
    leafletOptions(
      crs=leafletCRS(
        crsClass="L.Proj.CRS.TMS",
        code='EPSG:28992',
        proj4def='+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857330322398,0.350732676542563,-1.8703473836068,4.0812 +no_defs',
  c(-285401.92, 22598.08, 595401.9199999999, 903401.9199999999),
    resolutions = c(3440.640, 1720.320, 860.160, 430.080, 215.040, 107.520, 53.760, 26.880, 13.440, 6.720, 3.360, 1.680, 0.840, 0.420),
      )
  )) %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate='http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/tms/1.0.0/brtachtergrondkaart/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
  tileOptions(minZoom=3,maxZoom=13,tms=TRUE,continuousWorld=TRUE)   ) %>%
  setView(52,5.1,13)
```

This is an example in Javascript that has done the same thing:
http://bl.ocks.org/webmappergists/raw/1ceac1353920b3810486/

Comment: deleting the transformation between proj4def and resolutions also changes nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the map is gray because you mixed up the coordinates. Just change the view from `setView(52,5.1,13)` to `setView(5.1,52,13)` and the map should render. It will be wrong though.

You had a few errors in your code. First you forgot to define the *projectedBounds*. You just added the vector without defining or doing anything whith it. It should look something like this:

```
projectedBounds = c(-285401.92, 22598.08, 595401.9199999999, 903401.9199999999))
```

So the entire crs should look like this:

```
minZoom = 0
maxZoom = 13
resolutions <- 0.42*(2^(maxZoom:minZoom))

epsg28992 <- leafletCRS(crsClass = 'L.Proj.CRS.TMS', code = 'EPSG:28992',
                       proj4def = '+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs',
                       resolutions = resolutions,
                       projectedBounds = c(-285401.92, 22598.08, 595401.9199999999, 903401.9199999999))
```

Then you just have to add the tiles, set the view and you're done.

Entire code:

```
library(leaflet)

minZoom = 0
maxZoom = 13
resolutions <- 0.42*(2^(maxZoom:minZoom))

epsg28992 <- leafletCRS(crsClass = 'L.Proj.CRS.TMS', code = 'EPSG:28992',
                       proj4def = '+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs',
                       resolutions = resolutions,
                       projectedBounds = c(-285401.92, 22598.08, 595401.9199999999, 903401.9199999999))

leaflet(options = leafletOptions(
                                  crs = epsg28992, 
                                  minZoom = minZoom, maxZoom = maxZoom)) %>%
  setView(5.092098, 52.093992, zoom = 4) %>%
  addTiles('http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/tms/1.0.0/brtachtergrondkaart/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', options = tileOptions(tms=TRUE))
```